# Creating and joining non-rectangular banners in CSS

Tags: html, css, clip-path

I'm looking at replicating the following layout for my website using purely CSS.

[image: Slanted Banners]

My problem is that the banners will be images, and when I try to use something like a polygon clip-path, the images don't meet up.

Here's an example I've put together. What I'm looking for is a responsive way to make each banner perfectly line up. Please bare in mind that these images may change to square versions on mobile devices. Is there any better way of doing this to achieve what I'm trying to do?

```css
body {
            max-width: 1200px;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .banner-container {
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
        }
        .banner-container img {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .banner-container__1 img {
            clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 75%);
        }
        .banner-container__2 img {
            clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 0% 100%);
        }
        .banner-container__3 img {
            clip-path: polygon(0% 25%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%)
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Slanted Banners</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="banner-container banner-container__1">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x400/FF0000/FFFFFF%20?text=Placeholder" alt="Placeholder"/>
</div>
<div class="banner-container banner-container__2">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x400/0000FF/FFFFFF%20?text=Placeholder" alt="Placeholder"/>
</div>
<div class="banner-container banner-container__3">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x400/FF0000/FFFFFF%20?text=Placeholder" alt="Placeholder"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use only one clip-path with the middle element and consider some negative margin to overlap the others:

```css
body {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0;
}

.banner-container {
  position: relative;
}

.banner-container img {
  width: 100%;
  display:block;
}

.banner-container__2 {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 0% 100%);
  margin:-10% auto;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-container banner-container__1">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x400/FF0000/FFFFFF%20?text=Placeholder" alt="Placeholder" />
</div>
<div class="banner-container banner-container__2">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x400/0000FF/FFFFFF%20?text=Placeholder" alt="Placeholder" />
</div>
<div class="banner-container banner-container__3">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x400/FF0000/FFFFFF%20?text=Placeholder" alt="Placeholder" />
</div>
```

In case you need better support you can use skew transformation like below:

```css
body {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0;
}

.banner-container img {
  width: 100%;
  display:block;
}
.banner-container  {
 overflow:hidden;
}
.banner-container__1 {
  margin-top: -10%;
  transform:skewY(5deg);
  transform-origin:top left;
}
.banner-container__1 img {
  transform:skewY(-5deg);
  transform-origin:bottom right;
}
.banner-container__3 {
  transform:skewY(-5deg);
  transform-origin:bottom left;
}
.banner-container__3 img {
  transform:skewY(5deg);
  transform-origin:top right;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-container banner-container__1">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x400/FF0000/FFFFFF%20?text=Placeholder" alt="Placeholder" />
</div>
<div class="banner-container banner-container__2">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x400/0000FF/FFFFFF%20?text=Placeholder" alt="Placeholder" />
</div>
<div class="banner-container banner-container__3">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x400/FF0000/FFFFFF%20?text=Placeholder" alt="Placeholder" />
</div>
```

Comment: The negative margin definitely did work in this scenario - but I ended up opting for an SVG overlay instead.